# Excel - Calculate Holiday Taken

Tags: excel, math, computation

Tricky question. I need a way to analyse staff's holidays. Ensuring that 40% is taken before 31st August, 35% before 31st Dec, and 25% before March 31st.

[image]

This images shows the dates of an employee who worked from 1st of August, to the 1st of Feb. They are entitled to 50 hours holiday.

Below shows they took 10 hours before the end of August, 15 between August and Dec, and another 5 in the last part of the year. They still have 20 hours to choose when to take.

[image]

My goal is get something like this.

But this is the tricky part... The image above needs to account for the hours they would have had if they worked a full tax year.

If this employee, for example, started 1st of August, and you did 40/35/25% of their 50 hours, you'd get 20 hours that would need to be taken just in the month of August alone.

Rather I need to calculate 40/35/25% of what they would have been allowed to take in a full year, then apply it to those percentages correctly.

For example. If an employee started 1st Sept, and finished 31st Dec, the bars would show 100% for 1st March - 31st August, and a 100% for Jan 1st - March 31st.

Please ask if you need me to clarify these details.